# css, z-index, overflow, Facebook xfbml and Safari

Tags: css, facebook, safari, overflow, z-index

I'm trying to get the Facebook "Like" button xfbml dialogue to overlay a `<div>` in a site, but no matter what I do with z-index and overflow:visible, the dialogue won't be rendered above the `<div>` in Safari 5 and the edges are hidden.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bs4aJ/

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `overflow:hidden` on `#main` is clipping it. You can use the "clearfix" trick instead of using `overflow:hidden` to make `#main` wrap its floated children:

```
#main:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work in either the fiddle or my live site.

Comment: Did you remove the `overflow:hidden`?

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Bs4aJ/4/. At least for me, the little comment dialog is no longer clipped by the white box (though it is still clipped by the jsfiddle box, so you can't see the whole thing).